# Send 64-bit integer over Qt Socket

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I can't seem to figure out how to send a quint64 in network byte order over a QSslSocket.  I've done quite a bit of searching today and it's starting to give me a headache.

```
quint64    m_ack;
QSslSocket m_socket;
```

I'm using 'qToBigEndian' to get it into network byte order.

```
quint64 ack_be = qToBigEndian(m_ack);
```

Now I've tried a few methods to get that number to be written to the socket, but they all segfault.

```
m_socket.write((const char*)(ack_be), sizeof(quint64));
m_socket.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ack_be), sizeof(quint64));
```

I'd rather use std::uint64_t instead of quint64, but qToBigEndian fails with:

```
test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `unsigned long qbswap<unsigned long>(unsigned long)'
```

For reference, quint64 appears to be 'long long unsigned int'

I'm using Qt5 with c++11 support enabled.  Also, note, this is not me returning a TCP ack, this is just part of a protocol I'm interfacing with.

Thanks.

Comment: See this example project - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert qint64 or quint64 into QByteArray using QDataStream. (Like described in Qt examples)

```
QByteArray array;
qint64 m_ack = 255;
QDataStream stream(&array, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << m_ack;
```

To be sure of what you send, display your data with:

```
qDebug() << "array sent:" << QString(array.toHex());
```

as a result: "array sent: 00000000000000FF"